# Why does a SizedBox in another SizedBox ignore its width and hight?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I nest two SizedBoxes, the width and height of the inner box are ignored. Why is this, how can I work around it?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: SizedBox(
      width: 300,
      height: 500,
      child: SizedBox(
          width: 200, height: 200, child: Container(color: Colors.green)),
    ));
  }
}
```

[image]

In this example, I have a 300x500 sized box and an inner 200x200 SizedBox. In the picture you can see that the green box is the size of the outer SizedBox but should actually be a 200x200 square.

Comment: see https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints - at the end they have some examples - check them out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, SizedBox can set widget size only within the constrains set by the parent. Many widgets, like Padding, want their child to occupy 100% of the space available to them. This makes sense, because if the child is smaller they wouldn't know where to put it.

If you want the child to be smaller than the parent you could use Center or Align, e.g. replace

Answer (score 9):

`According to flutter documentation`: If given a child, this widget forces it to have a specific width and/or height. These values will be ignored if this widget's parent `does not permit them`. For example, this happens if the parent is the screen (forces the child to be the same size as the parent), or another SizedBox (`forces` its child to have a specific width and/or height). This can be remedied by wrapping the child SizedBox in a widget that does `permit` it to be any size up to the size of the parent, such as `Center or Align`.

So wrapping the child with center would solve the problem:

```
Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 300,
          height: 500,
          child: Center(
            child: SizedBox(
                width: 200, height: 200, child: Container(color: Colors.green)),
          ),
        )),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved my problem using the [FractionallySizedBox class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html).

You can specify the suitable size using fractions of the above `SizedBox` as `widthFactor` and `heightFactor`:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox.expand(
      child: FractionallySizedBox(
        widthFactor: 0.5,
        heightFactor: 0.5,
        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
        child: DecoratedBox(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.blue,
              width: 4),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```